# Can I use the word "not" after a preposition?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, clauses, dependent-clause

Can I write something like:

> among people from that country and among people from not

I know it can be easily rewritten as:

> among people that are from the country and among people that are not

But I just wonder whether the first writing is grammatically correct?  If it is, is it formal or informal?

Comment: I've never encountered that usage.  One may ask whether he is from that country or not.  "Is he from England or not?".  But "from not" is at best definitely not standard usage.

Comment: What you mean to say is "among people from that country and among people who are not" -- Now that there's no *from*, there's no question of *from not* -- there **may** be other cases where *from not* may occur naturally by semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English structure always demands commutative symmetry, if an arrangement is commutative.

That is to say,

- if the order of phrases can be switched and yet retain the same meaning, then their structure must be symmetrical.
- if a phrase can be factored into a parent and two or more child phrases, then the child phrases must be symmetrical.

For example,

> He can play the piano and he is a singer.

Wrong/unbalanced factorization:

> He can play the piano and a singer.

Correct factorization:

> He {can play the piano} and {is a singer}.

Commutation of the two child phrases that had been factored correctly will bear the same meaning:

> He {is a singer} and {can play the piano}.

Your phrase is not symmetrical

> among people from that country and among people from not

because commutation of the child phrases exposes the weak and unacceptable structure

> among people from not that country and among people from

The flaw is revealed by your implication

> among people from not that country

Since the structure of your phrase in question is unsound, the question you pose is moot.

Anyway, the acceptable way to factorize your sentence should be

> Among people {from} and {not from} that country

Where the two balanced child phrases are {*from*}, {*not from*}. The common factored phrase is

> Among people xxx and yyy that country.

Regardless of your question, it is possible to terminate a phrase with *from*. That is provided you are not among people who compulsively object to terminating phrases with prepositions.

- You will never reach your goal in life if you do not know where you are going to or coming from.
- I think I know which clan the Chosen One will be coming from.
- It is not the food that kills you, but which plate you have been eating from.

I am comfortable with terminating a phrase with a preposition, if that preposition is preceded by a verb or adverbial phrase.

- come from
- eat from
- going to
- comfortable with
- {picking up} from
- {feel comfortable} with
- {infatuated badly} with
- {feel horrid} about

For example,

> I do not know what I am {feeling horrid about}, but this is not the time for anything to {be horrid about}. I am glad I am surrounded by company I am comfortable with, because I always know where they are coming from.

I am unable to think of any possibility I would be comfortable with terminating a phrase with a preposition that is not preceded with a verb or adverbial phrase.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive explanation of the English structure.  I have learned a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason why ‘not’ cannot follow a preposition—in the right context.

The sentence you have given here, however, is not the right context.

What comes after a preposition is the preposition’s *object*. In the first part of your sentence, that object is “that country”.

In the second part of your sentence, “not” is what comes right after the preposition, and the reader therefore naturally interprets that as the object of the preposition. In other words, you read it as the second part of the sentence being about people who come from a place called “not”. That makes no sense.

If you want to avoid having to repeat too much, you can simplify the negated clause quite easily—but you shouldn’t move the negation ‘not’ to a different place in the clause just because you’re removing some unnecessary repetition:

> Among people from the country and people not from the country =>
>   Among people from the country and [people] not from [the country] =>
>   *Among people from the country and not from.

If you remove the repeated items in square brackets, you end up with the last sentence above. That sentence is not correct, though. The preposition ‘from’ needs and object: a preposition cannot stand on its own without an object anywhere. You can get around this in two ways:

- Use ‘there’ as a replacement (you can then also use ‘those’ as a replacement for ‘people’, just to make it clear that you're talking about two different groups of people);
- Move the contrast back to the thing it's contrasting with. In this case ‘not from’ contrasts with ‘from’, so you can simply say “(both) from and not from”:

> Both among people from the country and those not from there.
>   Among people both from and not from the country.

Answer (score -1):

Your first writing is not grammatically correct. In that sentence, the second time you use from, you establish a new preposition that would need a new object in which to refer to. There is generally an object preceding the preposition, but in the very least the preposition must have one.

> ...among people from *that* country and among people from *this* country.

Could be correct because their is an object for both prepositions.

The latter sentence is correct, but would be considered informal.

Comment: There is not generally an object preceding a preposition—that would make it a postposition.

Comment: I actually wrote the wrong word. I actually meant to say that the object of the preposition generally follows the preposition.

Comment: English does not actually have postpositions in a strict since. While you can occasionally allow the object to come before the preposition, it's merely a matter of stylistic choice, as opposed to obligatory reasons. 

I could say, "These considerations notwithstanding" but that is simply a stylistic choice contrasted to "Notwithstanding those considerations". So English does not have specifically postpositions, but many prepositions can act as such if one chooses.

Comment: That is not true. _Ago_ is a postposition only, as is the rarer and more formal _hence_.